# Unable to accept answer to this question

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I set up a bounty for the following question. The bounty period expired but the highest-voted didn't get auto-accepted and I don't see the check mark to accept it. I'd like to accept [graphicdevine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022207/blueprint-push-column-partially-in-to-another-column/2027014#2027014).

[Blueprint: Push column partially in to another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022207/blueprint-push-column-partially-in-to-another-column)

**Is there any way to accept the highest-voted answer so that it doesn't count against my "accept rate"?**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065

Answer (score 0):

Once the bounty expires, there's no going back.  It's total commitment.

Comment: Right, but usually the highest-voted answer gets auto-accepted. That didn't happen in this case.

Comment: You have to have at least 2 votes to get the auto-accept.

Answer (score 0):

The highest voted new answer with at least two votes gets autoaccepted.

If the answer was posted before you set the bounty, or it's less than 2 votes, then it won't be auto accepted.

If you allow the deadline to pass without selecting an answer, and none is eligible, then no answer will be chosen.  Further, once the bounty process ends the accepted answer cannot be changed.